# I don't have an idea how to program this using 2d array and JOptionpane

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Write a program using two-dimensional array that searches a number and display the
number of times it occurs on the list of 12 input values. Input/output should be in GUI.
Enter twelve numbers: 15 20 30 45 15 43 45 34 15 22 20 12
Enter the number to be searched: 15
Occurrence(s): 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note on multi dimensional arrays

```
// 0 as no match setting for index change to 1 on multi[1] if found 
    int[][] multi = new int[2][]; // 2 X not index
    multi[0] = {15,20,30,45,15,43,45,34,15,22,20,12};
    multi[1] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

If the user inputs 12 numbers you will need to collect them as strings and count the inputs until 12 then convert them to int as you put them on the [O] array or if they are matched as String they will require use of String.indexOf(testsrting) and reset corresponding index.

```
    String nomatch = "0";
    String match = "1";
int matchcount=0;
    String[][] multi = new String[2]; //
    multi[0] = new String[12];
    for (int i=0; i < 12;i++){
    multi[0][i]=new String("");
    }
    //
    multi[1] = new String[12];
    for (int in=0; in < 12;in++){
    multi[1][in]=new String("0");
    }
```

If you are searching just a single character then join all the strings to loop over and use substr() or substring() method of String to remove each character singularly and compare to the search character with indexOf()

You need to instantiate a basic gui with JFrame , 2 x jtextfield (enter numbers enter search value), jbutton and jlabel to inform user after button click , for your main class.
Joptionpane can be instantiated from a static class method call
And an actioneventlistener for the button.

There are checks on the entered search value to ensure substr() or substring() cuts the correct or CAN cut the right quantity to match.